# Check string formating

Tags: python, regex, csv

I need to check the first value on a csv file. It need to match an specific string. "ddd.ddddd" all numbers. All CSV values start and end with ""

Sample string from CSV

```
"123.12345"
```

The code so far is

```
import re
import csv

strformat = re.compile('\"\d{3}\.\d{5}\"')

with open(final_file, newline='') as fin:
    for f in csv.reader(fin[0]):
        if strformat is not None:
            print ("Match")
        else:
            print ("No Match")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse your code like this,

```
# The expression is changed
strformat = re.compile(r'\d{3}\.\d{5}') 

with open(final_file, newline='') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        # You have to check match like this
        if strformat.match(row[0]):
            print ("Match")
        else:
            print ("No Match")
```